# At symbol not cancelling double quotes?

Tags: c#

why is `var sydney = new Countries() { Name = @"<Image Source="Coors.jpeg" /> Sydney" };`

flagging at the Coors.jpeg with syntax error, comma expected.

Comment: When you use verbatim string (@) you need to use double double quotes for double quotes.

Comment: `@` escapes backslashes, not quotes; if it escaped quotes how would you end the string? To escape a quote, double it; `@"<Image Source=""Coors.jpeg"" /> Sydney"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment when using verbatim string you need to double the double quotes. ie:

```
var sydney = new Countries() { Name = @"<Image Source=""Coors.jpeg"" /> Sydney" };
```